# creating new object instead of assigning existing object POST in DRF

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

Recently we have been moving from traditional view to API Views so started implementing DRF.
so, my main problem is im having a model with a foreign key to another model
say

```
class Task(model.Models):
   created_by=models.ForeignKey(User, null=true, blank=true)
   assignees = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name="assignees", blank=True)

class UserSerializer(serializer.ModelSerializer):
   class Meta:
       model = User

class TaskSerializer(serializer.ModelSerializer):
   created_by = UserSerializer()
   assignees = UserSerializer(many=True, required=False)
   class Meta:
       model=Task
```

now when i create a task with User(pk=10) already existing user.
A new user is created instead of assigning the existing user.

```
here is my input:
{
  "created_by": {
    "id": 10,
    "email": "xyz@gmail.com",
    "name": "abc def"
  },
  "assignees": []
}
here is the output:
{
  "id":23,
  "created_by": {
    "id": 11,
    "email": "xyz@gmail.com",
    "name": "abc def"
  },
  "assignees": [
  ]
}
```

Got some help from Linovia: with this :-  https://gist.github.com/xordoquy/78a2d0e2ec85e2d7aadf
but the test case fails.
could any one suggest me im in need of it.

Answer (score 0):

Probably using [PrimaryKeyRelatedField](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations#primarykeyrelatedfield) may do the work.

```
class TaskSerializer(serializer.ModelSerializer):
    created_by = serializeres..PrimaryKeyRelatedField()
    assignees = UserSerializer(many=True, required=False)

    class Meta:
        model=Task
```

And updating your json to:

```
{
  "created_by": 10,
  "assignees": []
}
```